# Maven. error code 400

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, maven

i get error code 400 if i run Maven in my project. Problem appears when i run appengine:update maven. I am newbie it this thing, and I have no idea how to solve it.  Console code is :

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building helloworld 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.4:update (default-cli) @ helloworld >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ helloworld ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Laurynas\Documents\ud859-master\Lesson_2\000_Hello_Endpoints\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ helloworld ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.4:endpoints_get_discovery_doc (default) @ helloworld ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] Google App Engine Java SDK - get endpoints discovery doc...
[INFO] Using Class Name:com.google.training.helloworld.HelloWorldEndpoints
[INFO] Executing endpoints Command=[get-discovery-doc, -cp, C:\Users\Laurynas\Documents\ud859-master\Lesson_2\000_Hello_Endpoints\target\helloworld-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\classes;C:\Users\Laurynas\Documents\ud859-master\Lesson_2\000_Hello_Endpoints\target/classes;C:\Users\Laurynas\.m2\repository\com\google\appengine\appengine-api-1.0-sdk\1.9.4\appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.4.jar;C:\Users\Laurynas\.m2\repository\com\google\appengine\appengine-endpoints\1.9.4\appengine-endpoints-1.9.4.jar;C:\Users\Laurynas\.m2\repository\javax\inject\javax.inject\1\javax.inject-1.jar, -o, C:\Users\Laurynas\Documents\ud859-master\Lesson_2\000_Hello_Endpoints\target/generated-sources/appengine-endpoints/WEB-INF, -w, C:\Users\Laurynas\Documents\ud859-master\Lesson_2\000_Hello_Endpoints\target/generated-sources/appengine-endpoints, -f, rest, com.google.training.helloworld.HelloWorldEndpoints]
Oct 13, 2014 7:55:47 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\Users\Laurynas\Documents\ud859-master\Lesson_2\000_Hello_Endpoints\target/generated-sources/appengine-endpoints\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
API Discovery Document written to C:\Users\Laurynas\Documents\ud859-master\Lesson_2\000_Hello_Endpoints\target\generated-sources\appengine-endpoints\WEB-INF/helloworldendpoints-v1-rest.discovery
[INFO] Using Class Name:com.google.training.helloworld.HelloWorldEndpoints
[INFO] Executing endpoints Command=[get-discovery-doc, -cp, C:\Users\Laurynas\Documents\ud859-master\Lesson_2\000_Hello_Endpoints\target\helloworld-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\classes;C:\Users\Laurynas\Documents\ud859-master\Lesson_2\000_Hello_Endpoints\target/classes;C:\Users\Laurynas\.m2\repository\com\google\appengine\appengine-api-1.0-sdk\1.9.4\appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.4.jar;C:\Users\Laurynas\.m2\repository\com\google\appengine\appengine-endpoints\1.9.4\appengine-endpoints-1.9.4.jar;C:\Users\Laurynas\.m2\repository\javax\inject\javax.inject\1\javax.inject-1.jar, -o, C:\Users\Laurynas\Documents\ud859-master\Lesson_2\000_Hello_Endpoints\target/generated-sources/appengine-endpoints/WEB-INF, -w, C:\Users\Laurynas\Documents\ud859-master\Lesson_2\000_Hello_Endpoints\target/generated-sources/appengine-endpoints, -f, rpc, com.google.training.helloworld.HelloWorldEndpoints]
Oct 13, 2014 7:55:48 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\Users\Laurynas\Documents\ud859-master\Lesson_2\000_Hello_Endpoints\target/generated-sources/appengine-endpoints\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
API Discovery Document written to C:\Users\Laurynas\Documents\ud859-master\Lesson_2\000_Hello_Endpoints\target\generated-sources\appengine-endpoints\WEB-INF/helloworldendpoints-v1-rpc.discovery
[INFO] Endpoints discovery doc generation done.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ helloworld ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Laurynas\Documents\ud859-master\Lesson_2\000_Hello_Endpoints\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ helloworld ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ helloworld ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.4:war (default-war) @ helloworld ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [helloworld] in [C:\Users\Laurynas\Documents\ud859-master\Lesson_2\000_Hello_Endpoints\target\helloworld-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp webResources [C:\Users\Laurynas\Documents\ud859-master\Lesson_2\000_Hello_Endpoints\target/generated-sources/appengine-endpoints] to [C:\Users\Laurynas\Documents\ud859-master\Lesson_2\000_Hello_Endpoints\target\helloworld-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [C:\Users\Laurynas\Documents\ud859-master\Lesson_2\000_Hello_Endpoints\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [120 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: C:\Users\Laurynas\Documents\ud859-master\Lesson_2\000_Hello_Endpoints\target\helloworld-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.4:update (default-cli) @ helloworld <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.4:update (default-cli) @ helloworld ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] Google App Engine Java SDK - Updating Application
[INFO] 
[INFO] Retrieving Google App Engine Java SDK from Maven
[INFO] Updating Google App Engine Application
Oct 13, 2014 7:55:51 PM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
Reading application configuration data...
Oct 13, 2014 7:55:53 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:/Users/Laurynas/Documents/ud859-master/Lesson_2/000_Hello_Endpoints/target/helloworld-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
Oct 13, 2014 7:55:53 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:/Users/Laurynas/Documents/ud859-master/Lesson_2/000_Hello_Endpoints/target/helloworld-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF/web.xml


Beginning interaction for module default...

com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/getresourcelimits?app_id=4%2F1e6iuYCq-9PmtUjnsue-BvLgxVA5.AqgIEkLJxc8aPvB8fYmgkJxNIrjjkQI&version=1&
400 Bad Request

Client Error (400)
The request is invalid for an unspecified reason.

Unable to update app: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/getresourcelimits?app_id=4%2F1e6iuYCq-9PmtUjnsue-BvLgxVA5.AqgIEkLJxc8aPvB8fYmgkJxNIrjjkQI&version=1&
400 Bad Request

Client Error (400)
The request is invalid for an unspecified reason.

Please see the logs [C:\Users\Laurynas\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg2453046990150190280.log] for further information.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Update

```
Unable to update:
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/getresourcelimits?app_id=4%2F1e6iuYCq-9PmtUjnsue-BvLgxVA5.AqgIEkLJxc8aPvB8fYmgkJxNIrjjkQI&version=1&
400 Bad Request

Client Error (400)
The request is invalid for an unspecified reason.

    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.send1(AbstractServerConnection.java:293)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.send(AbstractServerConnection.java:253)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.post(AbstractServerConnection.java:232)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.LoggingClientDeploySender.send(LoggingClientDeploySender.java:47)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.ResourceLimits.remoteRequest(ResourceLimits.java:173)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.ResourceLimits.request(ResourceLimits.java:139)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.doUpdate(AppAdminImpl.java:467)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.update(AppAdminImpl.java:55)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg$UpdateAction.execute(AppCfg.java:1347)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.executeAction(AppCfg.java:332)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:213)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:124)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.main(AppCfg.java:120)
    at com.google.appengine.appcfg.AbstractAppCfgMojo.executeAppCfgCommand(AbstractAppCfgMojo.java:248)
    at com.google.appengine.appcfg.Update.execute(Update.java:32)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AdminException: Unable to update app: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/getresourcelimits?app_id=4%2F1e6iuYCq-9PmtUjnsue-BvLgxVA5.AqgIEkLJxc8aPvB8fYmgkJxNIrjjkQI&version=1&
400 Bad Request

Client Error (400)
The request is invalid for an unspecified reason.

    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.doUpdate(AppAdminImpl.java:479)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.update(AppAdminImpl.java:55)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg$UpdateAction.execute(AppCfg.java:1347)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.executeAction(AppCfg.java:332)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:213)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:124)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.main(AppCfg.java:120)
    at com.google.appengine.appcfg.AbstractAppCfgMojo.executeAppCfgCommand(AbstractAppCfgMojo.java:248)
    at com.google.appengine.appcfg.Update.execute(Update.java:32)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/getresourcelimits?app_id=4%2F1e6iuYCq-9PmtUjnsue-BvLgxVA5.AqgIEkLJxc8aPvB8fYmgkJxNIrjjkQI&version=1&
400 Bad Request

Client Error (400)
The request is invalid for an unspecified reason.

    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.send1(AbstractServerConnection.java:293)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.send(AbstractServerConnection.java:253)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.post(AbstractServerConnection.java:232)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.LoggingClientDeploySender.send(LoggingClientDeploySender.java:47)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.ResourceLimits.remoteRequest(ResourceLimits.java:173)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.ResourceLimits.request(ResourceLimits.java:139)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.doUpdate(AppAdminImpl.java:467)
    ... 29 more
```

Comment: I can add any info needed, that could help

Comment: Is there any additional information in the log at `C:\Users\Laurynas\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg2453046990150190280.log`?

Comment: Can you show your maven file ...

Comment: make a screenshot of maven file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm maybe or not but it seems like you need to enter your credentials in order to upload your application:

> To upload an app created with the the appengine-skeleton-archetype:
>
> Change directory to the top level of your project (for example, myapp)
>   and invoke Maven as follows:
>
> mvn appengine:update You will be prompted for an authorization code in
>   the terminal window and your web browser will launch with a consent
>   screen which you must accept in order to be authorized. Follow the
>   prompts to copy any codes from the browser to the command line.